# MYSQL multiple event in a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

How can I create a trigger for this two CHECK constraint

```
create table section ( course_id varchar(8), 
    sec_id varchar(8), 
    semester varchar(6) 
    check (semester in ('Fall', 'Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer')), 
    year numeric(4,0) 
    check (year > 1701 and year < 2100), 
    building varchar(15), 
    room_number varchar(7), 
    time_slot_id varchar(4), 
    primary key (course_id, sec_id, semester, year), 
    foreign key (course_id) references course on delete cascade, 
    foreign key (building, room_number) references classroom on delete set null);
```

========================================================================

Except for a solution.

Comment: You might want to use an ENUM datatype for the semester column instead. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

Uzzal,

As explained in the article, "[Validating data using a TRIGGER](http://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/validating-data-using-a-trigger/)," you should use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to validate your data, like so:

```
-- validate semester
CREATE TRIGGER `semester_validate_semester_insert`
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON `section`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
            IF NEW.`semester` NOT IN ('Fall', 'Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer') THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '[table:section] - `semester` column is not valid';
    END IF;
END;
```

and

```
-- validate year
CREATE TRIGGER `semester_validate_year_insert`
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON `section`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
            IF NEW.`year` <= 1701 OR NEW.`year` >= 2100) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '[table:section] - `YEAR` column is not valid';
    END IF;
END;
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Uzzal, happy to help! Please let me know if you have any other questions!! :0)